# Decrementing iterator after each loop iteration shows weird behavior

Tags: c++, list, debugging, iterator

I created a program to try to practice on the semantics of the list data structure. I noticed a weird difference in the following pieces of code:

First code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    list<int> l;
    int n = 100;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        l.push_back(i);
    }
    list<int>::iterator it = l.end();
    it--;
    for(; !l.empty(); it--) {
        cout << "the size of l is " << (int) l.size() << endl;
        l.erase(it);
    }
}
```

Second code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    list<int> l;
    int n = 100;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        l.push_back(i);
    }
    list<int>::iterator it = l.end();
    it--;
    for(; !l.empty();) {
        cout << "the size of l is " << (int) l.size() << endl;
        l.erase(it--);
    }
}
```

The objective of both pieces of code is simple - to simply erase all the elements in a list.

The only difference between them is the place where the list iterator is decremented.
In the first code sample, I used the for-loop control flow to decrement the iterator. In the second, I used the post-decrement operator to decrement the iterator.

Based on my understanding, the above code samples should be equivalent because I decrement the iterator **immediately** after I erase an element from the list. Furthermore, according to the STL docs, only the iterator to the erased element in the list is invalidated. So there should not be any undefined behavior.

The problem is, the second code sample works as expected - it stops after erasing all elements in the list. However, for the first sample, the list size could even become negative?! When I tried increasing the initial number of elements in the list, the first program crashes halfway.

Could someone kindly advise me on why these code samples behave differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 1st code has undefined behavior. As you said, `erase` makes the iterator invalid, the `it--` evaluated after that leads to UB.

The 2nd code is fine; note the evaluation order is different. `it--` will decrement the iterator, then return the original value (that's the point of post-decrement operator). The original value is passed to `erase` later. Decrement happens before `erase` so it's fine.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the clarification. I interpreted it as, the erase happens first, followed by the decrement. Hence, I got messed up.

Comment: In other words, because the decrement operator returns the value of the original iterator, the `erase` can happen and the iterator can still be valid. As opposed to the other code, which decrements an already invalid iterator. Just trying to say things different ways, so maybe more people can understand easier.

Comment: @LanceHAOH You must miss the nice point of post-decrement operator. :)

Comment: @songyuanyao I feel bad now. You are right. From the STL docs "Post-increment and post-decrement creates a copy of the object, increments or decrements the value of the object and returns the copy from before the increment or decrement.". All my life, I thought that post-decrement/increment operator will return the original value followed by applying the increment/decrement operation.

Comment: @ChristinaJacob Undefined Behavior = Anything could happen.

Comment: @LanceHAOH Look at it from another angle, as an operator (or function), when it returns, the invocation ends. It's impossible to perform decrement after returning. So it must perform the decrement then return the original value copied.